# Upper bound for a graph related finite sum

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, summation

At the moment I am looking into undirected graphs $G=(V,E)$ with node set $V=\{1,\ldots,M\}$ and edge set $E$. We can assume that they are connected by the way. Lets denote edges from $i$ to $j$ by $(i,j)\in E$, define the neighbor set $\mathcal{N}_i$ of some node $i$ by:
$$\mathcal{N}_i :=\{j \: | \: (i,j)\in E\},$$
and denote by $d_i$ the degree of node $i$.

Now, I would like to show that for any connected undirected graph we have:

$$\sum_{i=1}^M\left( \: \sum_{j\in \mathcal{N}_i} \frac{x_i^2 - x_ix_j}{\max\{d_i,d_j\}+1} \right) = \sum_{(i,j)\in E} \frac{(x_i-x_j)^2}{\max\{d_i,d_j\}+1} \leq \frac{3}{2},$$
for any $x = [x_i] \in \mathbb{R}^M$ with $x^Tx =\sum_{i=1}^Mx_i^2=1$. The first equality is true, I already know that; I write them both to give two possible expressions to work with. It is the upper bound that I am interested in.

I would like to show this because (1) it is convenient for me to know whether this is true (a counter example would also be nice to have otherwise) and (2) I have a good suspicion that this is true by doing many numerical computations*.

*Actually, this question is an alternative formulation for a question I posted earlier about [a lower bound for the smallest eigenvalue of a doubly-stochastic-matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1800892/interval-bounds-for-symmetric-doubly-stochastic-matrices-designed-with-metropol) (designed by the so called Metropolis weights). This alternative formulation is derived by the expression for the [field of values of any matrix $A$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_range).

Comment: Since this sounds like research-level math, you might have better luck getting an answer on [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/).

Comment: That's a good point, that seems like a better place to ask. Thanks for the tip!